# conflict between for loop and array calling

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have been working on this for hours now and I can't find the error. I've tried many things without success and searched everywhere for the answer. Hope someone can help.

Here's the code:

```
function eventpopup(date) {

            if(popupstatus == true){

                $( "#eventinfopopup" ).animate({ "left": "-=300px" }, "slow" );
                $( "#eventinfopopup" ).promise().done(function(){
                document.getElementById("popupcontent").innerHTML = "";
                $( "#eventinfopopup" ).animate({ "left": "+=300px" }, "slow" );
                for(i = 0; i <= eventcontent[date].length; i++){
                    document.getElementById("popupcontent").innerHTML += "<img class='popupbanner' src='" + eventcontent[date][i]['bannerimg'] + "' />";
                    document.getElementById("popupcontent").innerHTML += "<h2 class='popupeventtitle'>" + eventcontent[date][i]['title'] + "</h2>";
                    document.getElementById("popupcontent").innerHTML += "<span class='popupdate'>" + eventcontent[date][i]['datetime'] + "</span>";
                    document.getElementById("popupcontent").innerHTML += "<p class='popupfulldesc'>" + eventcontent[date][i]['fulldesc'] + "</p>";
                }
            });
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("popupcontent").innerHTML = "";
                $( "#eventinfopopup" ).animate({ "left": "+=300px" }, "slow" );
                for(i = 0; i <= eventcontent[date].length; i++){
                    document.getElementById("popupcontent").innerHTML += "<img class='popupbanner' src='" + eventcontent[date][i]['bannerimg'] + "' />";
                    document.getElementById("popupcontent").innerHTML += "<h2 class='popupeventtitle'>" + eventcontent[date][i]['title'] + "</h2>";
                    document.getElementById("popupcontent").innerHTML += "<span class='popupdate'>" + eventcontent[date][i]['datetime'] + "</span>";
                    document.getElementById("popupcontent").innerHTML += "<p class='popupfulldesc'>" + eventcontent[date][i]['fulldesc'] + "</p>";
                }
                popupstatus = true;
            }

        }
```

I don't know where the problem is coming from. It seems to be coming from the "for" loop. If I adapt the code to not have a "for", it works fine.

There seems to be an issue between the for loop and my request in the array. when I have the for loop, I receive an error message in the debug console saying that the "bannerimg' is undefined. Remove the for loop and it's all gone, everything works fine...

probably something stupid but I can't figure it out.

thanks.

Comment: You've failed to quote the error message. Please post it as it is.

Comment: If you remove the loop, then how do you access `eventcontent[date][i]['bannerimg']`? `i` should be `undefined`.

Comment: In your for loop try changing `<=` to `<`

Comment: I just replaced it for `[0]`

Comment: @Evan Carslake I have murder envy right now... It worked... can't believe it was just that. been working on that for hours... THANK YOU!

Comment: @EvanCarslake That should be an answer, since it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop try changing `<=` to `<`.